# How to play local XviD (.avi) files that are chosen by the user in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, avi, flash-video

So I'm building a web application, and in part of the application the user should choose an XviD (.avi) video file from his machine, to be played in the browser (without uploading it). I decided to use Flash for this.

Now I have two questions about this:

- Which Flash video player is free to use and capable of doing this?
- How should I let the user choose a video file, and how can I link the Flash video player to the file?

Comment: duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958141/play-local-video-from-web-browser ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't. The Flash plugin don't have enough privileges to access the user's local file system.

Comment: How about using the JavaScript window.URL.createObjectURL()? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.URL.createObjectURL) I know this makes it possible to do the same thing with the HTML5 video tag, except that the HTML5 video tag can't play XviD video files.

Comment: Never used it, so I cant't say. But it's worth a try!

Comment: Flash Player has some file system access, so a user could select a local file for use. But Flash can't play XviD or .avi files, so what Cokegod wants to do can't be done with Flash anyway.